# about Independent configuration item in webpack config

Tags: webpack

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
  ...
  },
  output: {
  ...
  },
  resolve: {
  ...
  },
  resolveLoader: {
  ...
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: utils.cssLoaders({ sourceMap: useCssSourceMap }),
    postcss: [
      require('autoprefixer')({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm the beginner of webpack, recently I start a project using webpack and vue, and I search documents on the Internet to build webpack config, I have a question about the code:

why there are **vue** and **eslint** 2 independent configuration item in the code,I have search a lot documents about this question but I haven't find a solution, I wish some one who can help me about this question :)